# I will get array as (id,name,email) from front end.How should i handle it in a SP for inserting that data in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert data in a table profile (id,name,email).How should i handle it in a SP ?

I will be getting array as (1,rahul,rahul@gmail.com),(2,rohit,rohit@gmail.com).

Comment: What version of SQL Server (2008,2012,etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user defined table type. Something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ttUsers] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    [email] varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUsers(@Users [dbo].[ttDocumentFacilities] READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT Users (id, name, email)
    SELECT id, name, email
    FROM @Users;
END


var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("id");
dataTable.Columns.Add("name");
dataTable.Columns.Add("email");

var users = new SqlParameter("@Users", SqlDbType.Structured)
{
    Value = PopulateTableRows(ids, dataTable),
    TypeName = "dbo.[ttUsers]"
};
```

Note I haven't implemented all methods but should give you an idea of how to do it

Comment: thnkx, let me try  this